# how to get max value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an issue where I'm trying to aggregate results in a way that is most convenient.

Let's say the table I'm querying has 6 columns that are relevant to me, columns a through f; columns d and e are times and f is an alpha value that I think isn't relevant for this exercise

The current query I have is

```
select * from mytable where b in (list of values)
```

the problem is b appears multiple times

- with unique a (primary key)
- and c (primary key from a different table

What I want to do is group by column b, but only return the rows with the max value of c for every b

[image: table]

The query I had is `select b, max(c) from table where b in (range) group by b`

Whenever I try to add the other columns, I get an error like

> 'not a GROUP BY expression'

but I only want to group by b

So in that table, What I want to return is

| A (id) | B (group by) | C (id_other max) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | 9 |
| 10 | 2 | 12 |
| 15 | 3 | 6 |
| 20 | 4 | 10 |

along with the other columns d through f, but I don't think their values are relevant, if they are, please let me know.  I've been going through a ton of sites and books looking for guidance regarding max and group by, but haven't been able to figure this out. please let me know if I need to provide some additional information. thanks!

I tried something like select b, max(c), a, d, e, f from table where b in (range) group by b, but it doesn't work

Comment: What is the underlying database system [tag:rdbms]? Is it [tag:mysql] or [tag:sql-server] or [tag:postgresql] or [tag:sqlite] or ...?

Comment: sorry for the lack of clarity, this is an oracle database to which i have read-only access. i'm using sql developer

Comment: Is Max(c) always unique? Or can there be cases like below where b=2 and Max(c) =4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there are not multiple identical c, you can use

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1 JOIN (SELECT b, MAX(c) max_C FROM table1) t2 
ON t1.b = t2.b AND t1.c = t2.max_c
```

or if your database suppirts cte and window functions and you have multiple identical c

```
WITH CTE as    
(select t1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b ORDER BY c DESC,a DESC) rn
    from table1 t1)
SELECT a,b,c FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: `row_number()` is the answer, and you can do it without a CTE (if you need to) by nesting the selects.

Comment: no, CTE or a subquery in FROM is needed, because Window function have to parse the complete result Table to get their numbers, and so can't be used in the HAVING clause.

Comment: You can get the same effect by nesting the SELECTs:  `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT row_number() ...  ) t WHERE t.rn = `

Comment: CTE and subqueries in the fridge m are the same, so I will behave the same

Answer (score 0):

For [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) i created [this sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/94be5/1)

Create a simple table

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    A_id int, B int, C_id int
);
```

Add some data to it

```
-- group by b but select only record where c is max
INSERT INTO my_table (A_id, B, C_id)  VALUES (1,2,3);
INSERT INTO my_table (A_id, B, C_id)  VALUES (2,2,4); -- this c_id=4 or
INSERT INTO my_table (A_id, B, C_id)  VALUES (3,2,4); -- that c_id=4 or both?
INSERT INTO my_table (A_id, B, C_id)  VALUES (4,3,40);
INSERT INTO my_table (A_id, B, C_id)  VALUES (5,3,41); 
INSERT INTO my_table (A_id, B, C_id)  VALUES (6,3,42); -- only this 
INSERT INTO my_table (A_id, B, C_id)  VALUES (7,4,50);
INSERT INTO my_table (A_id, B, C_id)  VALUES (8,4,51);
INSERT INTO my_table (A_id, B, C_id)  VALUES (9,4,52); -- only this
```

The Inserts above create these records

[image: records from above]

And then query the data

```
SELECT my_table.A_id, sq.B, sq.C_Max FROM 
   (SELECT B, Max(C_id) as C_Max FROM my_table GROUP BY B) as sq
LEFT JOIN my_table ON sq.B = my_table.B AND sq.C_Max = my_table.C_id;
```

This part `SELECT B, Max(C_id) as C_Max FROM my_table GROUP BY B` gets all records where C_id has the highest value and only includes column B and C.
This result can be used to join the result with the table itself to find the matching rows.

[image: sqlfiddle result]